# How can I replicate New-SmbGlobalMapping in C# code?

Tags: powershell, docker, winapi

I am writing a service which controls docker containers. I want to have the mounted volume as an Azure share, and thus need to use the SMB Global Mapping. If I use the usual WNetAddConnection2A then I can mount the share just fine in my code, but the containers cannot see it as it is not "global". I can't find source for the PowerShell New-SmbGlobalMapping command (is there a way to see it?) and I can't find a suitable API to call. I hope someone knows the magic incantation I can put in my .NET code.

Comment: Why not just call `New-SmbGlobalMapping` from C#?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen I could, but I much prefer to get tighter control over errors and options available. For a simple connection, I can also disconnect it and make new if the requirements change. Keeping things under complete control is my ideal.

Comment: Ehh, calling the cmdlet doesn't give you complete control? Nothing stops you from passing the same parameters to it programmatically as anyone sitting at the command line

Answer (score 2):

> I can't find source for the PowerShell New-SmbGlobalMapping command
>   (is there a way to see it?) and I can't find a suitable API to call. I
>   hope someone knows the magic incantation I can put in my .NET code.

PowerShell uses **WMI**

In your case, it calls
[Create method of the MSFT_SmbMapping](https://learn.microsoft.com/previous-versions/windows/desktop/smb/msft-smbmapping-create) class (*MSFT_SmbGlobalMapping* exactly)

You can use [WMI Code Creator](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8572) to generate/test C# code

---

**EDIT** : Test with [PowerShell.Create](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.powershell.create?view=pscore-6.2.0)

- Test as Admin ("*requireAdministrator*" in manifest) on Windows 10
- Test code (C#, VS 2015) =>

```cs
    // PowerShell calls CredUIPromptForCredentialsW to display the User/Password dialog (you can call it with P/Invoke if needed)
    string sUser = "user@provider.com";
    string sPassword = "myPassword";
    System.Net.NetworkCredential networkCredential = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(sUser, sPassword, null);
    System.Security.SecureString securePassword = new System.Security.SecureString();
    foreach (var c in networkCredential.Password)
        securePassword.AppendChar(c);
    // Add reference to :
    // C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\WindowsPowerShell\3.0\System.Management.Automation.dll
    // Add :
    // using System.Management.Automation;
    PSCredential psCredential = new PSCredential(networkCredential.UserName, securePassword);

    // Error handling must be improved : if I pass an invalid syntax for "RemotePath" or not launched as Admin,
    // nothing happens (no error, no result) (on Windows 10)
    string sLocalPath = "Q:";
    string sRemotePath = "\\\\DESKTOP-EOPIFM5\\Windows 7";
    using (var ps = PowerShell.Create())
    {
        ps.AddCommand("New-SmbGlobalMapping");
        ps.AddParameter("LocalPath", sLocalPath);
        ps.AddParameter("RemotePath", sRemotePath);
        ps.AddParameter("Credential", psCredential);
        //ps.AddParameter("RequireIntegrity", false);
        //ps.AddParameter("RequirePrivacy", false);    
        try
        {
            System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection<PSObject> collectionResults = ps.Invoke();
            foreach (PSObject psObl in collectionResults)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Status : {0}", psObl.Members["Status"].Value.ToString());
                Console.WriteLine("Local Path : {0}", psObl.Members["LocalPath"].Value.ToString());
                Console.WriteLine("Remote Path : {0}\n", psObl.Members["RemotePath"].Value.ToString());
            }
        }
        catch (ParameterBindingException pbe)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine("\rNew-SmbGlobalMapping error : {0}: {1}",
                          pbe.GetType().FullName, pbe.Message);
        }
    }
    // To get and remove the test mapping in PowerShell :
    // Get-SmbGlobalMapping
    // Remove-SmbGlobalMapping -RemotePath "\\DESKTOP-EOPIFM5\Windows 7" -Force
```

Comment: Thanks - trying to get this to work. The code creator isn't creating code that works for the basic call to ManagementObject, so learning how to get that working!

Comment: Okay, use ManagementClass - will post complete code once working. Right now got to work out how to pass in the credentials.

Comment: And stuck at "Invalid parameter" in the ManagementBaseObject outParams = classInstance.InvokeMethod("Create", inParams, null); call. It doesn't give a clue as to what might be wrong, and I cannot find anything on the web that gives a clue as to the parameters!

Comment: Yes, I just did some tests and I also get "Invalid parameter" atm.... Otherwise, you could use  the.[PowerShell Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.powershell?view=pscore-6.2.0)

Comment: Getting the credentials for the PowerShell option is the main problem. There do appear to be ways to feed the password in, but really it's not a nice option. I wish Microsoft had documented the underlying API!

Comment: @mj2008 The PowerShell New-SmbGlobalMapping command seems use [Get-Credential](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.security/get-credential?view=powershell-6) to get user name and password.

Comment: I tested with  **PowerShell.Create** and it worked (I used _System.Management.Automation.PSCredential_ for the Credential)

Comment: @Castorix Do you have sample code? That would be perfect!

Comment: @mj2008 Ok, I will edit my answer asap (I only have "draft code" with tons of commented lines atm with all the tests I did...)

Comment: @Castorix Thanks - I wish it would work instantly. On my dev machine, it says it doesn't know the command, even though I can type it okay. On the server, it can't find the powershell.command.dll. I shall persist!

Comment: After trying for a few days, I gave up. I could not get code to work on any machine, each failing in different ways. I typed the command instead. For shame! I just hope it persists.